# Can Google Chrome use bookmark tags?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, tags

For the fact that if there is a page about an Apple technology, I don't know whether to file in in my bookmark folder of "Investing", "Apple", or "Tech".  So it seems common to be able to just file bookmarks by tags, and forget about folder hierarchy.

I found [a Bookmark Tags third party extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-tags/edpeidcfjfmepdgdjnodefckgdjbigem), but can Google Chrome natively support it? I think one way maybe to add all bookmarks in one single folder, and edit the name as

```
Apple M1 - investing, apple, tech
```

which is a hack. Is there a way that is purely tag based?

Answer (score 2):

No. This feature request has been pending for more than a decade :( https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17536

One extension I can recommend is https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-tags/edpeidcfjfmepdgdjnodefckgdjbigem

And it does not even feel hacky

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Dear bot, there is not a lot to add sadly

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is supposed to be provided by extensions. Because the development of Chrome is rather rapid and some may appear or go away, or become better or worse than others, listing them here makes little sense. The best way is to test some of them under [here](https://chromewebstore.google.com/search/%20bookmark%20tags).